# Download .xls file using Angular: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: c#, json, angular, typescript, http

I have the following server method for returning an `byte[]` for an `xls` document stored in `Azure Blob Storage`.

```
[FunctionName("ReadBatchFile")]
        public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReadBatchFile([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, WebRequestMethods.Http.Get, Route = "Agreements/ReadBatchFile")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            try
            {
                var fileName = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                   .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "fileName", true) == 0)
                   .Value;
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(await AzureHelpers.ReadFromBlobStorage(fileName));  //returns byte[] 
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = fileName };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message);
                req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

As can be seen from the above, the `response.Content` is set an `ByteArrayContent` and my `contentType` is `application/octet-stream`.

In `Angular`, I have the following method in my service to call the above function.

```
readBatchFile(fileName: string): Observable<Blob> {
    let endpoint = environment.endpoints.agreement.baseUrl + environment.endpoints.agreement.readBatchFile + "&fileName=" + fileName;
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ contentType: 'application/octet-stream' })}; //application/vnd.ms-excel   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    return this.http.get<Blob>(endpoint, httpOptions);
  }
```

Although I am specifying that the `contentType` is `application/octet-stream`, and that my `get` method should return a `Blob` type, I still get the following error:

> Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0↵    at JSON.parse
>   ()

Why is `Angular` still seeing the response from the server as `JSON`?

**Update**

Here is my request headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer ...
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/batches
responseType: application/octet-stream
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=B4debe034-efc6-416f-8082-422a4122a857_MTN_Upgrade_20181017_T065548.xls
Content-Length: 3011
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 06:55:48 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

And the Response:

```
PKø6QMäH­¯3[Content_Types].xmlµÏJ1Æ_eÉU´D¤ÛªU°>ÀÌvCóÌ´¶oo6+"¥z$ßÌ÷ý3_¼köÉÆÐÆM+ÞÖ[ÑC0àbÀVÄr1_RSfµ¢gNwJîÑÉ0¥ÙkÞ¨zT×ÓéÒ10ðà!ó{ì`ç¸Yïu+ %g5pÁRÅL4"Ã]ýanÌ    ÌäDftµzèê4 ¨4$<ÉÖà¿"b×Y&ê/#RF0Ô#²w²VéÁ1ô2?/®êàÔGÌÛ÷·²j"êù·ü*ªevAâ£C:G1*î!£yå\ü<ÁÏoU~ñ   PKäH­¯3PKø6QMÚë®'_rels/.relsÏÁ0àWYzc1ájðæVÖe
oïb<xlú÷ûÓ²^æ=Ñ¬"Ë¡U¤kÜÚËî,DiµÈ¢ÔUyÅIÆtúÁô1ºçAõ8ËC6ùYÆ4zÃT£4È÷y~àþÓ­É-À7ºÖ®ÿ±©ëgRmüQñH²ô£eâ/òãhÌ
¼*ùæÁê
PKÚë®'PKø6QMæl($×Sxl/workbook.xmlO½NÄ0~È;ÂpBUÛ`9    é{Hkt]9)åÝx$^ôª
F&ö÷cûûó«9|Ä ÞQgjávWB²Ü{:·0ews®Y.oÌUÔjiaÈy¬µNvÀhÒG¤Â9hriå¬Ù9oñí²¾«ª½&Miðc5í?Yi4}skT4 k«^=Îé÷È¥UºkôîjÝª"±$Muûò>(©}rì^26£5Á>rSèÍêXTÛêîPKæl($×SPKø6QMb¢Ö4xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels­ÏjÃ0_Åè¾8é`Q·1èµ@ØJØÆÒÚåík6VR(cdôý>¬åúkÔ2÷1hª]:ýÇÓ+(ÈÀDëÕrKJYaß'VØIoZ³õ4"W1Q(/mÌ#Jis§Ú#v¤uý¢ó·LµqòÆ5 öS¢ÿ°cÛöÞ£ý)È}ùÈH
sGbà:bý]ªPAßY<ReÊ_^M~ú¿âï1ÛI.[ÌÇ¿2úæÚ«PKb¢Ö4PKø6QMÄÎ«hïxl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlËr0F_a_Ðýâ±Iã:ñ®ÓE»¦¶äpwë¢ÔW¨ÀÄ7 Ðù~I
ðïÏßùÃG~Þ±.!@¨b«wYñºOåþó³6o6Uª^ØYiYgql·©Êé£*\ß^<)Ý¥yõ~mÕJoO¹*ÊÀb£Ié²iv´á¥Ú=µìÑ¨dWO!?\JåIVËù.sÕ«ÙFíá#mHÄËy
ÿÌÔÙÞ´j%¿µ~«.6»Ej6öàu=øwìÔ>9Êúü¢²×´thÙê­AUêÂ O>êó9Û©k¡!Â\ÇödKÿjºÃø&8jã<J±LFã¸ãÛÑ!Å  $ÆI'·q! ¥
Î)<mâôÇe!8ÀÑÑ8kâìÀ
/³Ñ8oâüg#&¥ «M\\ã p½Clâò§nòHp¡tÒñeóÔ;mÉrnô90U¯+]5q[oO·ã¬»û¾óø½6ÄW]âÉ'PXùîß|tµOÐ.ñì¬K¼øï-;{­BÔ*D^DöúìY~@zWH-c    "$§C"z6§«­ÞS{@zíezeQ¤£·Jñ¤Rð }¥ø~¥ÓÕÖH_éÒW:½²Í(ÒQJZ¥dR©OxJ¾Rr¿Òéjë¤¯té+^Ùf¹(oÞ£©ûMPf­u©Lýeo]ÿPKÄÎ«hïPKø6QM"tÛ4SÎ
xl/styles.xmlR½nÃ ~ÄÞGjUU¶3T²Ô%K:tÅ6ØHp ÀÝWëÐGê+°8Q¥Lw|þ~ð?_ßù~TuBC³Í#nt<xÆû2w~ìØ3æQà+pï½y!Ä5=SÔm´a¾pmõáh;âe´uQ¤$Ùm·ODQ¸ÌaPò5z_àIÊk¸@üNT$K, ÍÀ+¢¶"¡dæ¦âRHy¶Úá(sC½gªp@Kÿ>V`ÐÀD¼Cï,²ÝãZJH®µmÃ,×¿1Ce.÷QaE×§ÆkK­½×*v­ *ïliwÃ¤<Æ=|ð«£y omeÂÒF£µl6¹£§ÆÈé0¨Ù*­3ÒÖ®PéYF~vÎI©WQgÅ=øýåÊ£ôþ»~0mG~óhÈåa¿PK"tÛ4SÎPKø6QMPùûxl/sharedStrings.xmlm]k0ÿJÈ}h][Z2è2Ðþ ÇfsÛ¿_ÆØÖË<ÏÄ=±wp8Zð`/9ÓØv4}ÂoõóîÌ2­¬rvIcDbþªÁDó£Ø îíÆÎ:­È]/pv ZHO"ò(´
g]ù²gßÈþ/1¦1¥Eu­ò2ÆâüÐêZ°Ò®ijÇ2ÛÂRtÇ^TóªzØÌÿºZ¹±ë6#O
ù¥1¾o$h×¾¨Kû¥mñÌj
píä)ÑÃñt^WdT6p åNkq{§þ!ü¦_PKPùûPK-ø6QMäH­¯3[Content_Types].xmlPK-ø6QMÚë®'Y_rels/.relsPK-ø6QMæl($×S@xl/workbook.xmlPK-ø6QMb¢Ö4Txl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPK-ø6QMÄÎ«hïrxl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlPK-ø6QM"tÛ4SÎ
 xl/styles.xmlPK-ø6QMPùû®xl/sharedStrings.xmlPKÂë
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting from Angular 9 there are four response types supported: `'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text'`.

For file contents you want to use the `blob` response type, which you can set in the get-request directly like this:

```
return this.http.get(endpoint, { responseType: 'blob'});
```

More information is [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) in the docs.

Your `content-type` header is only used for the request-header, it does not influence the response.

**Old Answer (up to Angular 8)**

You can set the `responseType` in the get-request directly like this:

```
return this.http.get(endpoint, { responseType: 'application/octet-stream'});
```

Comment: I have tried this. Stil get the same error in the console

Comment: Can you post the request sent and the response received?

Comment: Your updated data looks all good. My mistake, obviously responseType is not a header-paramter but an Angular HttpClient param. I updated the answer.

Comment: When doing this in Angular 8 (using HttpClient) I get the error "Type '"application/octet-stream"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.ts"

Is there a similar solution for Angular 8, where HttpClient has to be used?

Comment: when I set responseType: 'text/csv' or somehing, I get error what @LeBavarois's has. only json settable for responseType (on angular 9.1.0)

Comment: @ddagsan I meanwhile solved this problem, check out my answer below

Comment: @LeBavarois I had to do this in my http request { responseType: 'blob' as 'json'});

Answer (score 11):

For Angular 8+

```
return this.http.get(endpoint, { responseType: 'blob'});

return this.http.post(endpoint, postParams, { responseType: 'blob'});
```

It is subtle but if you look at the docs you will notice `http.post` and `http.get` does not take a generic return type of `<T>` when we set `responseType: 'blob'`.  So we don't need the `<Blob>` part in `http.get<Blob>` anymore.  Which makes sense when you think about it since we are telling HttpClient the response is of type `blob` with `responseType: 'blob'`.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post

[image: Angular 8 HttpClient blob doc]

If you need something besides 'blob' here are the other options available for responseType.

```
responseType: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text'
```

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#responseType

Comment: Same result with angular 8+

Answer (score 4):

I resoloved the problem in Angular 9.1.4 by using responseType blob and setting type in BlobPropertyBag later, e.g. for Excel files:

```
 return this.httpClient.get(url, {
  responseType: 'blob',
  params: queryParams
})
  .pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      const blob = new Blob([res], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
      return blob;
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this On angular 9.1.0 with following code:

```
result = this._httpClient.get(url,
{
  responseType: 'blob',
  headers: headers
});
```

Comment: In case it does not allow you to simple change the response type, you can have { responseType: 'blob' as 'json'});

Answer (score 0):

Wish it help anyone..

```
 { responseType: 'blob' as 'json'}
```

**doesn't go in the headers object..**